# Is it possible to modify a "human" user so that it becomes a system user on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, user-accounts, ubuntu-18.04, user

I followed a guide to set up etherpad-lite on my ubuntu server (https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-etherpad-on-ubuntu-18-04/). At one point, I had to create a new user with `sudo adduser --home /opt/etherpad --shell /bin/bash etherpad`.

It is the second time that I set up a server, but it already bothered me that you have to create a new "human" user for each service. So I looked to see if there was a better way and stumbled upon system user. Now I know that you can create new system users with `sudo adduser --system --group <name>`, but is it also possible to change an existing user to a system user?

Comment: Decent question… But does it actually matter? Maybe it can help in easier differentiation between system and “human” users, but it might also run into a situation where the custom system user is not clear and you might assume a user you added was a part of the OS.

Comment: That's a good point. The main reason why I prefer system users is their limitations. As far as I understand this it helps with the server's security (not 100% sure though tbh).

Comment: I’ve never seen the placement of the user into system users versus make a bit of difference as far as security goes. As long as their groups and permissions are secure, it really makes no difference. For example, as long as that user is not part of `sudo` rights and must `sudo` with a password, the user is secure. Believe it or not many people — instead of using `root` — will setup a standalone user with password-less `sudo` and that is self-defeating to say the least.

Comment: I believe u xD bc I did this with my first server hahaha. Thank u very much for the explanation/clarification 

Comment: No problem! Also, if you want to safely experiment with server configs, please look into using VirtualBox with Vagrant. Or just VirtualBox. You setup a clean Ubuntu server there and then experiment. You screw up? Who cares. It’s a VM and easily disposable. Remember, blowing up VMs costs nothing. Blowing up the OS on a “real” machine of some kind — or a VM not in your control — will only cause frustration and headaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `usermod` to change the account's UID to a value between 1 and 999. On most Linux distributions, the range 1–999 indicates system accounts while 1000– is for "human" users.

(Some older distributions use 1–499 and 500–, or in some really old cases 1–99 and 100–.)

Comment: Thx :) I knew about the UIDs already but wasn't aware that changing the UID is all it takes.

Comment: Don't forget to also change the gid of the group, change the file ownership uid and gid of files outside the home directory, delete the home directory, set the home directory to /nonexistant, and change the user's shell to nologin.